# JavaScript equivalent of C#'s Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.OnActivated event?

Tags: javascript, windows-10-universal

Universal Windows applications can be launched with arguments.
I'd like to obtain a reference said arguments.
In C# code examples, the function usually subscribes to `Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.OnActivated` and obtains arguments as part of the Event object. What is the equivalent way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: In what context are you using javascript?  Website, Node.js, or are you using javascript in some kind of interpreter like Titanium?

Comment: In a Universal Windows application.

Comment: looks like you answered it already.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for [`Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.onactivated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242314).